# C++ - Explicit & Implicit Namespace Implementation Differences

Tags: c++, namespaces, explicit-implementation

I have a question about namespaces if someone can enlighten me :D

I don't know if the title is right, I hope so xD

Code in the ".cpp" file is called the ***Implementation of the Namespace*** and the code in ".h" file is called the ***Declaration of the Namespace***? right? :/

Anyway, my Question is:

there is any difference by Explicit or Implicit Implementation of Namespace Members (in the ".cpp" file)?

I mean, let's suppose I have this namespace in "**MyNamespace.h**":

```
namespace MyNamespace {

    void fun_one(int a);

    void fun_two(int b);

}
```

**There is any difference** if in "**MyNamespace.cpp**" I do this **(Implicit Implementation)**:

```
namespace MyNamespace {

    void fun_one(int a){
        // CODE HERE...
    }

    void fun_two(int b){
        // CODE HERE...
    }

}
```

Or **this (Explicit Implementation)**:

```
void MyNamespace::fun_one(int a){
    // CODE HERE...
}

void MyNamespace::fun_two(int b){
    // CODE HERE...
}
```

## ?

Thanks you so much :D

Have a Nice day & a nice coding! (:

Comment: This is probably a matter of opinion. IMO, it is better to use the first approach. It avoids unnecessary duplicate typing of the namespace's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no difference between the 2 versions you have shown, and you can use whichever one you prefer.

For what it's worth, here's one case where it differs slightly:

```
namespace A 
{ 
  struct S{};
  S f();        // declare f
}
```

and then:

```
namespace A 
{
  S f() { return S{}; }   // define f, ok
}
```

is fine, but the following is not:

```
S A::f() { return S{}; }
```

since `S` is used before the introduction of namespace `A`. This can be fixed by doing:

```
A::S A::f() { return S{}; }
```

or

```
auto A::f() -> S { return S{}; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... called the *Implementation of the Namespace* ... *Declaration of the Namespace* ...

Nope. Namespaces just ... scope names. They don't have a distinct declaration and implementation like a function.

What you have is the declaration of two functions, and then the definition of those two functions. The functions have names, and those names are *scoped* by the containing namespace, but nothing's really different from functions with names at file scope.

Which syntax you chooses to refer to those functions, with their scoped names - even in the function definition - is just that, syntactic. It only affects how the code looks, and has no effect on what it does.